# Plotting rows with variable length categorical data

Tags: r

I've got data representing the dates on which a certain event occurred on which
nodes in a cluster.  The data currently look something like this:

```
07-Jan-2013: node025 node061
14-Jan-2013: node025 node034 node061
21-Jan-2013: node025 node034 node050 node061
28-Jan-2013: node025 node034 node061
04-Feb-2013: node025 node034 node061
11-Feb-2013: node025 node034 node061
18-Feb-2013: node034
25-Feb-2013: node034
11-Mar-2013: node025
```

I was wondering what sort of plot in R would enable me to plot the names of the
nodes as a factor on the y-axis against the date and what form the input date
should be in.

I have tried searching for "variable length row" and "multiple y values" but
couldn't find what I was looking for.  Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Use read.table with fill=T then filter out the blanks

Then melt the data to make it flat

```
df<-read.table( text="07-Jan-2013: node025 node061
14-Jan-2013: node025 node034 node061
21-Jan-2013: node025 node034 node050 node061
28-Jan-2013: node025 node034 node061
04-Feb-2013: node025 node034 node061
11-Feb-2013: node025 node034 node061
18-Feb-2013: node034
25-Feb-2013: node034
11-Mar-2013: node025", fill=T)

require(reshape2)
flatdata<-melt(df,id.vars="V1")

# edit added the date format
ggplot(flatdata[flatdata$value != "",])+geom_point(aes(x=value,y=as.Date(V1, format="%d-%b-%Y"),color=variable),size=5,alpha=0.9) + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Of the 3 three solutions to date, this matches my requirements best in that it is easy to see when the events occurred for a given node.  The only slight problem is that the colours do not convey any information.  Ideally the datapoints corresponding to a given node would all be the same colour.

Comment: Just another small question: how is the order on the y-axis determined?  It would be nice if the data could be arranged alphabetically.

Comment: I worked out a way of doing the ordering:  
    `flatdata$value -factor(flatdata$value,levels=sort(levels(flatdata$value)))`  
I guess there may be a better way.

Comment: That should be: `flatdata$value <- factor(flatdata$value,levels=sort(levels(flatdata$value)))`

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- readLines(n=9)
07-Jan-2013: node025 node061
14-Jan-2013: node025 node034 node061
21-Jan-2013: node025 node034 node050 node061
28-Jan-2013: node025 node034 node061
04-Feb-2013: node025 node034 node061
11-Feb-2013: node025 node034 node061
18-Feb-2013: node034
25-Feb-2013: node034
11-Mar-2013: node025

df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(strsplit(df, " "), function(row) {
  cbind(row[1], row[-1])
}))
df[,1] <- as.Date(df[,1], format="%d-%b-%Y:") 
plot(V2~V1, data=df) # defaults to spineplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A stacked bar chart will do this.

Here's your data:

```
lines <- readLines(
  tc <- textConnection("07-Jan-2013: node025 node061
  14-Jan-2013: node025 node034 node061
  21-Jan-2013: node025 node034 node050 node061
  28-Jan-2013: node025 node034 node061
  04-Feb-2013: node025 node034 node061
  11-Feb-2013: node025 node034 node061
  18-Feb-2013: node034
  25-Feb-2013: node034
  11-Mar-2013: node025")
); close(tc)
```

We split it into useful components and rearrange into a data frame.

```
split_lines <- strsplit(lines, ":? ")
dates <- as.Date(
  vapply(split_lines, head, character(1), n = 1),
  "%d-%b-%Y"
)
nodes <- lapply(split_lines, tail, n = -1)
n <- vapply(nodes, length, integer(1))

node_data <- data.frame(
  date = rep(dates, times = n),
  node = unlist(nodes, use.names = FALSE)
)
```

Plotting with ggplot is straightforward.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(node_data, aes(date, fill = node)) +
  geom_bar(binwidth = 1)
```

[image]